# Android: How to force createTabContent to create content in all tabs?

Tags: android, dynamic, tabs, android-tabhost

I`ve been playing with tabs recently and here is a problem. The following cycle creates dynamic tabs with dynamic layouts. However, when i run the app only the first tab content is created, and only if I try to select the second tab, then the second tab content is created.

I want to immediately access second tab layout, and if I try to do that from the first tab, before selecting second tab the app crashes.

```
    Tabs = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    Tabs.setup();       
        for (count =0;count < all_rooms_count;count++){
        NewTab.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory()
            {

                public View createTabContent(String tag)
                {
                  RelativeLayout ll = new RelativeLayout(MainActivity.this);
                    ll.setLayoutParams(params);
                    ll.setId(passedTabId);

                    return ll;
                }
            });

            Tabs.addTab(NewTab);
        }
```

Is it possible to force the cycle to create tab content for all tabs
?

Answer (score 0):

First of all its redundant to create a separate TabContentFactory for every tab. Its good idea to keep one instance of TabContentFactory and use it for all the Tabs.

The tab contents need not be created only inside the createTabContent method. You can create all the views at once (even outside) and return when corresponding tab bis selected.

```
RelativeLayout l1=..;
RelativeLayout l2=..;
RelativeLayout l3=..;
RelativeLayout l4=..;

TabContentFactory factory=new TabContentFactory(){

public View createTabContent(String tagId){

if(tagId.equals(TAG1))
    return l1;
}else if(tagId.equals(TAG2)){
    return l2;
}else if(tagId.equals(TAG3)){
    return l3;
}
};
```